# Is there a Ruby .NET Compiler?

Tags: .net, ruby, compiler-construction

Is there a .NET Framework compiler for the Ruby language? I've heard of the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime), is this going to enable Ruby to be used with .NET development?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) is a project supported by Microsoft, built on the Dynamic Language Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

[Yep, the Ruby.NET project](http://rubydotnet.googlegroups.com/web/Home.htm?gda=8ES3fzoAAACraJYLasopJnHm_A4zSrefscDsHtcsS-deqHbu90w8mzCLtOtCUOXSAV3CbWid_sX97daDQaep90o7AOpSKHW0).  Note, it hasn't been updated since November 2007, so I'm not sure what the support's like now.

Edit: As others have pointed out, IronRuby is supported by Microsoft, so it's probably a better idea

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative is [Iron Ruby](http://www.ironruby.net/), which is, I think, officially sanctioned by Microsoft.